# WERFAULT.exe - Bad image - policymanager.dll

Tags: windows-10

I am getting the dreaded WERFAULT.exe - Bad image error on Windows since yesterday. Here is what I have tried

- Restarted a few times
- Tried to open Settings - It opens and immediately closes
- Unable to turn on/off network connectivity as they are all inside the Settings
- Followed the [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance-winpc/bad-image-error-dll-file-error-windows-x-pro/14e711e7-8ce3-4829-ad41-7b3d369da168) however running DISM throws `Error: 1223` and running `sfc /scannow` throws an error `Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation`
- Logged out and tried the Shift + Power button -> Troubleshoot

  - Factory Image Restore - No images available.
  - Reset this PC - Tried both simple reset to keep files and deep reset to clear everything
  - Advanced options - Uninstall updates - Uninstalled both feature and quality update and neither finds anything.

It appears to me there should be a simpler way to get Windows to a known sane state. Are there any tricks I am missing?

Comment: Was the computer protection activated? Then could you try to load a system restore point. Press the **Windows** and **R** button at same time and then run the following command: `rstrui.exe`.

Comment: Unfortunately as far as I am aware of there isn't such a trick, your OS seems to be beyond redemption, even if there is such a trick it would probably be very complex and wouldn't worth it, I am sorry to say, but the harsh truth is, you need to perform a clean install at this point, it's the only reliable way, you need a WinPE rescue USB stick and a Windows 10 ISO image, both WinPE and Windows 10 are available on microsoft.com for free(WinPE available through WindowsADK, however you can also use WinRE.wim with Win10PXE Builder).